# Is a heatmap in "sized dot style" possible in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Is it possible to draw a heatmap with circles instead of square in ggplot2? It would be neat to not only represent the values by a color gradient but also by the circle size.
I am thinking of a graph like this [dot heatmap](http://www.pnas.org/content/105/52/20870/F2.large.jpg) where also the circle sizes are alternated by their specific value. I already read myself into heatmapping with ggplot2 but couldn't find  a solution. For heatmapping I alternated the example posted on learnr.wordpress.com to:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(plyr)
 library(reshape2)
 library(scales)
 kreuz <- read.csv("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/ppg2008.csv")
 kreuz.m <- melt(kreuz)
 (p <- ggplot(kreuz.m, aes(Name, variable)) +
   geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white") +
   scale_fill_gradient2(breaks=waiver(), name="binding strength", 
      low ="white", mid= ("lightblue"), high = "steelblue", midpoint = 4))
 base_size <- 10
 p + theme_grey(base_size = base_size) +
   theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())+
   labs(x = "Patient ID", y = "Phage Motives", title = "Cross Reactivity")+
   scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
   scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
   theme(legend.position = "right", axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
      axis.text.x = element_text(size = base_size *0.8, angle = 270, hjust = 0,
      colour = "grey50"))+
   labs(x = "Patient ID", y = "Phagemotives", title = "cross reactivity")
```

I would be very greatful for some hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example size and colour both correspond with the variable value because it's the only variable numeric available in the kreuz.m dataset.

```
ggplot(kreuz.m, aes(Name, variable)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = value, colour=value))
```