# Draw heatmap for a matrix using circle in R

Tags: r, heatmap

What I’d like to do is make a heatmap that has each of the values in the colored cells.

I have a matrix with some matrix values, not correlation (from 0 to 1).

```
data=read.table("1.csv", sep=",", header=T)
data
         LosAngeles   Seattle    SanDiego    Lynnwood

Seattle      0.1       1.0        0.3         0.4
Lynnwood     0.5       0.7        0.2         1.0
Washington   0.2       0.3        0.4         0.6
```

Unlike typical heatmap, I want to plot that in a graph that looks like that. For example, I’d like to display with color range in a circle going from light gray (value = 0) to dark blue (value = 0.8-1.0) with color label legend.

How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097136/row-column-heatmap-plot-with-overlayed-circle-fill-and-size-in-r and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358297/is-a-heatmap-in-sized-dot-style-possible-in-ggplot2?rq=1